# How to read value input type="date" for writing Database?

Tags: asp.net

I have problem that to read value `<input type="date" id="mydate" runat=""server/>` it is not like to read similar textbox as like `textbox1.text` .How can I get the value?

Comment: why don't you use asp.net textbox control?

Answer (score 1):

As you didnt mentioned your Framework , i'm assuming your using framework 4 .

So for Framework 4 and above, allows you to specify the type attribute.

[Refer this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2468871)

Please refer to the Feature 3

> Feature 3
>
> New syntax lets you define a TextBox control that is HTML5 compatible.
>   For example, the following code defines a TextBox control that is
>   HTML5 compatible:
>
> `<asp:TextBox runat="server" type="some-HTML5-type"/>`

**Update**

if you are using Older version of Framework here is work around

In **Aspx**

```
<input type="text" ID="txt1" runat="server"/>
```

In **.cs** :

```
string date = Request.Form["txt1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="date" id="mydate" name="mydate" runat="server"/>
```

Code behind:

```
string date = Request.Form["mydate"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get values of input type using Request.Form["Your Id of input type"]

```
DateTime dt = Request.Form["mydate"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery to get the value of a datetime control

```
$('#mydate').val();
```

if you are using ajax calls, send the value by converting that to a date format and send as ISO string

```
var v = $('#mydate').val();
var dt = new Date(v);
var str = dt.toISOString();
```