# System.IConvertible error on my TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the output on my label.when I got this error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

I already converted my code but I still get this error.

```
 protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity);
        double Price = Convert.ToDouble(lblPrice);
        double sum;

        sum = Quantity * Price;
        //Output
        sum = Double.Parse(lblPriceToBe.Text);
    }
```

Comment: ``txtQuantity.TExt``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the [`Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your `TextBox` and `Label` when you convert them `ToDouble`. It should be like this:

```
double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text);
double Price = Convert.ToDouble(lblPrice.Text);
```

**Edit**: To avoid getting the *input was not in correct format* error firstly make sure that you entered a valid number and secondly use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` like this:

```
double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
double Price = Convert.ToDouble(lblPrice.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Just don't forget to add this line to your `using` statements:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: Thanks.Now I'm having an error with my sum "input was not in correct format" error

Comment: My lblPriceToBe is the one causing the "input was not in correct format error". Also I tried the cultureInfo and it gives me a red underline.

Comment: @rainalasa...You should add this to your using statements: `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: "input was not in a correct format" was cause by my "sum = Double.Parse(lblPriceToBe.Text);" But let me try this for a bit

Comment: @rainalasa..Well you **should** also use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in that line: `sum = Double.Parse(lblPriceToBe.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Ok so I change my lblPriceToBe to your answer but it still gives me the "input string was not in correct format"

Comment: Ok so I change my lblPriceToBe to your answer but it still gives me the "input string was not in correct format"

Comment: @rainalasa...So I'm pretty sure that the number in lblPriceToBe is not a double number. What is that number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110839/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-s-akbari).

Answer (score 3):

You Need to use

`txtQuantity.Text` but not `txtQuantity`

and also

`lblPrice.Text` but not `lblPrice`

So on the whole it should look like the following way

```
double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text);
double Price = Convert.ToDouble(lblPrice.Text);
```

Comment: Now I'm having this errer >input was not in a correct format

Comment: this may be because the text is not a number

Comment: @rainalasa in framwork 4 you can set the `type' to number  please [refer this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279985/how-to-read-value-input-type-date-for-writing-database/36284773#36284773)

Comment: My problem now was the out put.   "sum = Double.Parse(lblPriceToBe.Text);" is giving me an error of "input was not in a correct format"

Comment: try using with  `Convert.ToDouble` rather than `double.parse`